# Using time() and clock() in C Problems

Tags: c, time

I'm working on a programming assignment and I'm getting strange results.
The idea is to calculate the number of processor ticks and time taken to run the algorithm.

Usually the code runs so quickly that the time taken is 0 sec, but I noticed that the number of processor ticks was 0 at the start and at the finish, resulting in 0 processor ticks taken.

I added a delay using `usleep` so that the time taken was non-zero, but the processor ticks is still zero and the calculation between the time stamps is still zero.

I've been banging my head on this for several days now and can't get past this problem, any suggestions are extremely welcome.
My code is below:

```
/* This program takes an input "n". If n is even it divides n by 2
* If n is odd, it multiples n by 3 and adds 1. Each time through the loop
* it iterates a counter.
* It continues until n is 1
*
* This program will compute the time taken to perform the above algorithm
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void delay(int);

int main(void) {
    int n, i = 0;
    time_t start, finish, duration;
    clock_t startTicks, finishTicks, diffTicks;
    printf("Clocks per sec = %d\n", CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);    // read value from keyboard
    time(&start);       // record start time in ticks
    startTicks = clock();
    printf("Start Clock = %s\n", ctime(&start));
    printf("Start Processor Ticks = %d\n", startTicks);

    while (n != 1) {    // continues until n=1
        i++;    // increment counter
        printf("iterations =%d\t", i);  // display counter iterations
        if (n % 2) {            // if n is odd, n=3n+1
            printf("Input n is odd!\t\t");
            n = (n * 3) + 1;
            printf("Output n = %d\n", n);
            delay(1000000);
        } else {                //if n is even, n=n/2
            printf("Input n is even!\t");
            n = n / 2;
            printf("Output n = %d\n", n);
            delay(1000000);
        }
    }
    printf("n=%d\n", n);
    time(&finish);      // record finish time in ticks
    finishTicks = clock();
    printf("Stop time = %s\n", ctime(&finish));
    printf("Stop Processor Ticks = %d\n", finishTicks);
    duration = difftime(finish, start); // compute difference in time
    diffTicks = finishTicks - startTicks;
    printf("Time elapsed = %2.4f seconds\n", duration);
    printf("Processor ticks elapsed = %d\n", diffTicks);
    return (n);
}

void delay(int us) {
    usleep(us);
}
```

**EDIT:** So after researching further, I discovered that `usleep()` won't affect the program running time, so I wrote a delay function in asm. Now I am getting a value for processor ticks, but I am still getting zero sec taken to run the algorithm.

```
void delay(int us) {
    for (int i = 0; i < us; i++) {
        __asm__("nop");
    }
}
```

Comment: `clock()` does not return "processor ticks", as will be obvious when you print the value `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Comment: `clock()` measures CPU time. Sleeping does not consume CPU time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the elapsed time using the below formula.

```
double timeDiff  = (double)(EndTime - StartTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC.
```

Here is the dummy code.

```
void CalculateTime(clock_t startTime, clock_t endTime)
{
   clock_t diffTime = endTime - startTime;
   printf("Processor time elapsed = %lf\n", (double)diffTime /CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to time an implementation of Goldbach's Conjecture. I don't see how you can hope to get a meaningful execution time when it contains delays. Another problem is the granularity of `clock()` results, as shown by the value of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

It is even more difficult trying to use `time()` which has a resolution of 1 second.

The way to do it is to compute a large number of values. This prints only 10 of them, to ensure the calculations are not optimised out, but not to distort the calculation time too much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SAMPLES 100000

int main(void) {

    int i, j, n;
    double duration;
    clock_t startTicks = clock();

    for(j=2; j<SAMPLES; j++) {
        n = j;                      // starting number
        i = 0;                      // iterations
        while(n != 1) {
            if (n % 2){             // if n is odd, n=3n+1
                n = n * 3 + 1;
            }
            else {                  // if n is even, n=n/2
                n = n / 2;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(j % (SAMPLES/10) == 0)   // print 10 results only
            printf ("%d had %d iterations\n", j, i);
    }

    duration = ((double)clock() - startTicks) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nDuration: %f seconds\n", duration);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
10000 had 29 iterations
20000 had 30 iterations
30000 had 178 iterations
40000 had 31 iterations
50000 had 127 iterations
60000 had 179 iterations
70000 had 81 iterations
80000 had 32 iterations
90000 had 164 iterations

Duration: 0.090000 seconds
```